# Access files from web.py urls

Tags: python, web-services, web-applications, web.py

I'm using web.py for a small project and I have files I want the user to be able to access in /files directory on the server. I can't seem to find how to return a file on a GET request so I can't work how to do this.

Exactly want to do essentially is:

```
urls = ('/files/+', 'files')

class files:

  def GET(self)

    #RETURN SOME FILE
```

Is there a simple way to return a file from a GET request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing around I came up with this webpy GET method:

```
def GET(self):
    request = web.input( path=None )
    getPath = request.path
    if os.path.exists( getPath ):
        getFile = file( getPath, 'rb' )
        web.header('Content-type','application/octet-stream')
        web.header('Content-transfer-encoding','base64') 
        return base64.standard_b64encode( getFile.read( ) )
    else:
        raise web.notfound( )
```

Other respondants are correct when they advise you consider carefully the security implications. In my case we will include code like this to an administrative web service that will be (should be!) available only within our internal LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the contents of a file and stream them down to the user, but I don't believe that a file handle is serializable.

It would seem to be a potential security hole to allow users to access and modify files on the server or to copy files down to their own machine.  I think you should reassess what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I essentialty want a user to be able to download a file that they have uploaded. Was going to use a randomly generated url to actually access the file but just need to work out how to return a file. Was just wanting the user to hit the url and get the 'save as' dialogue in their browser.

Comment: I don't see why you'd want it to be "random".  A REST API would have a unique key for the file as a parameter.

Comment: Actually yes you're right about that. But that's not really what I'm worried about. This is my first attempt at any sort of web development so not overly bothered about security etc.

Comment: Your users will be if they upload files to your site.  If you aren't going to think about security, why would I want to upload files for you to keep?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it by using generator and not reading the whole file into memory:

```
    web.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=%s" % doc.filename)
    web.header("Content-Type", doc.filetype)
    web.header("Transfer-Encoding","chunked")
    f = open(os.path.join(config.upload_dir, doc.path, doc.filename), "rb")
    while 1:
        buf = f.read(1024 * 8)
        if not buf:
            break
        yield buf
```

Comment: I've tried this method, but I get a network error when and download stops